# Error in Kotlin code generated in compile time

Tags: kotlin, runtime-error

I wrote the same code in Python with same logic but Kotlin doesnt show the value I want.

```
class LCMC {

    fun gcd(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a
        }
        return gcd(b, a % b)
    }

    fun lcm(n:Int) : Int {
        var ans = 1
        for (i in 1..n) {
           var ans = (ans * i) / (gcd(ans, i))
        }
        return ans
    }
}

fun main(){
    var objOfLCM = LCMC()
    println(objOfLCM.lcm(10))
}
```

The result should be 2520.
But in kotlin it is showing 1.

Comment: "Runtime error" usually refers to situations when a program crashes (stack overflow, devision by zero, etc.), not to incorrect output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're redefining your `ans` in the local context of the `for` loop.

Remove `var` from the inside of the `for` loop and you'll get the result you want:

```
fun lcm(n:Int) : Int {
    var ans = 1
    for (i in 1..n) {
       /*no var*/ ans = (ans * i) / (gcd(ans, i))
    }
    return ans
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is really helpful.